# In Flutter, what are the cases where you use timer.cancel() instead of timer = null?

Tags: timer, flutter

I'm looking at the [Flutter Timer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html) code and the `cancel()` method.
When I want to delete a timer, I can use these two lines:

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
```

or I can just do:
    timer = null;

But why do both cancel() and null? Why not do one or the other?

Specifically, I'm asking about when overriding a State's `dispose()`, if I know the widget is to be disposed anyway, should I be doing both or just one?

Another case: I see that I can use `if (timer == null) ...`, but if I were to just cancel the timer and not set it to null, I could equally use `if (timer.isActive)`.

Another case: I could see that if there were a `timer.restart()` method, it would make sense to use `cancel()` and reuse the timer. But since there currently isn't, I always have to create a new timer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `cancel()` you stop the timer and prevent the registered callback to be called (or be called anymore for `periodic` timers).

Setting the variable that holds a reference to the timer to `null` can be a flag to be used in your own logic (for example if the timer is not set (`== null`), set a new one
or it can just be to get rid of any references to the `Timer` instance so it can be garbage collected (like with any other object).

In `dispose()` just `cancel()` is enough.

> Another case: I see that I can use if (timer == null) ..., but if I were to just cancel the timer and not set it to null, I could equally use if (timer.isActive).

There is slight difference between a `Timer` not yet created or a `Timer` that is not yet expired and does not yet have called the passed callback.